# some confusion where $\alpha$ will convergent?

Tags: integration

Find the range of value of $\alpha $ for which $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}$ is convergent.

My attempts:  I  have  two answer in my mind  follows as given below

## First answer :

$$\sin x \le 1\implies\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}\le \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$$

So $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}$ is convergent if $\alpha > 0$

## second answer :By  using integration by part

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}= -[\frac{cosx}{x^{\alpha}}]_{0}^{\infty} - \alpha \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{cosx}{x^{\alpha +1}}dx$

Now i take $I = \alpha \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{cosx}{x^{\alpha +1}}dx$

From this i can conclude that $\alpha + 1 > 0 $,  implies $\alpha > -1 $ and again $0 < \alpha < 1$

So now that range of value of $\alpha$  for  convergent is $(-1,1)$

there fore $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}$ is convergent if $-1 < \alpha <1$

I m not  sure  which one will correct

any hints/solution will be more appreciated

thanks u

Comment: I think $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^\alpha} \, dx$ diverges for any $\alpha$.

Comment: @angryavian is right. Consider, though, that

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}\ \text{d}x = \cos \left(\frac{\pi  a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1-a)$$

With the necessary condition $0<\Re(a)<2$, so just work a bit more on it.

Comment: what is  R(a) ??   im not getting @VonNeumann

Comment: @jasmine It's the real part. Nobody said that $a$ is only real, it could also be a complex number like $a = p + iq$, hence what matters here is just $0 < p < 2$ (again: for a complex $a$).

Comment: @Von neumann that  mean answer will be  $0 < a < 2  $...This  question  came in my exam  see the Question No. 8   http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/assets/pdf/question_paper/Dec15.pdf

Comment: @jasmine That is the correct answer. Yet you shall show it, through some reasoning! Also, as I pointed out, the correct answer is not really $0<a<2$. This is true if $a$ si a real number, whilst if it's complex then you need its real part to be bounded between $0$ and $2$, them not included.

Comment: okks @VonNeumann  thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Near $0$, we have a positive integrand, so we can  use  *equivalents*: $\sin x$ is equivalent to $x$, so by the rules of asymptotic analysis,
  $$\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha}\sim_0\frac{x}{x^\alpha}=\frac1{x^{\alpha-1}}$$
  and $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac1{x^{\alpha-1}}\,\mathrm dx\;$ converges for $\alpha-1<1$, i.e. $\;\alpha <2$, hence the same is true for the given function on $(0,1]$.
- Near $\infty$, we can use *Abel's rule*: $\;\dfrac1{x^\alpha} $ decreases to $0$ for any $\alpha>0$, and $\;\displaystyle \int_1^x\!\!\sin x\,\mathrm d x$ is bounded, so the given integral converges on $[1,+\infty)$.

*Conclusion*: the integral converges  if $\;0<\alpha<2$.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is your use of "equivalent" a mathematically precise term or a shorthand for "if you expand $\sin x$ as a power series around 0..."?

Comment: @rafa11111: $f(x)\sim_0 g(x)$ means $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$. Very often, an equivalent of a function is obtained as the first non-zero term in a Taylor's expansion.

Answer (score 2):

For $\alpha\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}\cos(x)\\
&=\cos(1)-\alpha\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
which converges.

For $\alpha\lt2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_0^1x^{1-\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
which converges.

Thus, the integral converges for $0\lt\alpha\lt2$.

Furthermore,
$$ \newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\Im\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag1\\
&=\Im\left(i^{1-\alpha}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag2\\[6pt]
&=\cos(\alpha\pi/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha)\tag3\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi\alpha/2}{\sin(\pi\alpha/2)\,\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$(2)$: [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)
$(3)$: [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$(4)$: [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)